# can I implement this rest api call from a .bat file?

Tags: http, batch-file, request, client

Can I implement this REST API call from a `.bat` file? This is the request object:

```
public class ADEtlAction
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string[] Domains { get; set; }
}
```

This is what the **REST** call would look like:

POST api/v1/etl/actions
{
Type:"User"
Domains:["ad-domain-1", "ad-domain-2"]
}

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "implement this REST API call"? Do you mean *make* a call to the service from a batch file? Sure - assuming you have `wget`, `curl` or something similar available.

Comment: As Jon says, if you have a command-line program capable of acting as a HTTP client available, then yes. There isn't one directly as part of the batch command set, or the built in windows tools. This question doesn't really have anything to do with any of the tagged technologies, they're just the code used to implement the API, but to the client it's just a HTTP endpoint. I've changed them to something a bit more related to the client-side, since that's your question

Comment: You might be able to write your own helper program in .NET, or using Powershell, or use one of the tools Jon suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use external binaries, just try with [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat):

```
call winhhtpjs.bat "http://server/api/v1/etl/actions"  -method POST   -header hdrs.txt -saveTo response.file   -body-file some.json
```

and in the `some.json` you'll need to put the body of the request and if you need some headers you can put them in the `hdrs.txt` file.